# Does the = operator call the constructor/new in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, assign, assignment-operator

Say I have a (immutable) matrix class that dynamically creates an array in the constructor, and deletes it in the deconstructor.

```
template <typename T>
class matrix {
private:
    T* data;
public:
    size_t const rows, cols;
    matrix(size_t rows, size_t cols) : rows(rows), cols(cols) {
        data = new T[rows*cols];
    }
    ~matrix() {
        delete [] data;
    }
    //access data
    T& operator()(size_t row, size_t col) {
        return data[row*cols + col];
    }
    matrix<T>& operator=(const matrix<T>& other) {
        //what will this->data contain? do I need to delete anything here?
        //should I call the constructor?
        rows = other.rows;
        cols = other.cols;
        data = new T[rows*cols];
        std::copy(&data[0],&data[0] + (sizeof(T)*rows*cols),&other.data[0]);
        return *this;
    }
}
```

Because I don't have a default constructor within the `operator=` function, the data in `this` is just garbage, right? Even if I had a default constructor would it be called? I'm basing the above code off of the example [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment). Note that I have left out input validation/bounds checking for brevity.

EDIT:
I would like to clarify that I'm only concerned for a call like this:

```
matrix<int> A = B;
```

Where B has already been initialized.

Comment: You should be more concerned about the memory leak.

Comment: You forgot the user-defined copy constructor for `matrix<T>`.  If you wrote that first, then the assignment operator is very simple.,

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three

Comment: Huh. `this->data` will be what it was before you called `operator=`.

Comment: Your latest edit shows a call to the copy constructor, *not* assignment operator.  So my previous comment stands -- you need to write a copy constructor.

Comment: The original question is asked under the misconception that the assignment operator is involved.  Given the latest edit, it isn't involved at all.  Closing as "unclear".

Comment: In addition, if you wrote a copy constructor (and it is correct), then the example you linked to that uses `std::swap` in the assignment operator would be, more or less, how you would have written your assignment operator, i.e. using simple calls to `swap` all the members.

Comment: `matrix<int> A = B;` is *NOT* an assignment, it's an initialization.  So it does not use or call `operator=` at all -- it calls the copy constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Say I have a (immutable) matrix class that dynamically creates an array in the constructor, and deletes it in the deconstructor.

You are violating the [Rule of Three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) by not implementing a copy constructor (and the [Rule of Five](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)#Rule_of_Five) in C++11 by not implementing a move constructor and a move assignment operator).

Your copy assignment operator has a memory leak, as it is not `delete[]`'ing the old `data` array before assigning the `new[]`'ed array.

Try this instead:

```
template <typename T>
class matrix {
private:
    T* data;
    size_t const rows, cols;

public:
    matrix(size_t rows, size_t cols) : rows(rows), cols(cols) {
        data = new T[rows*cols];
    }

    matrix(const matrix<T> &src) : rows(src.rows), cols(src.cols) {
        data = new T[rows*cols];
        std::copy(data, &data[rows*cols], src.data);
    }

    /* for C++11:

    matrix(matrix<T> &&src) : rows(0), cols(0), data(nullptr) {
        std::swap(rows, src.rows);
        std::swap(cols, src.cols);
        std::swap(data, src.data);
    }
    */

    ~matrix() {
        delete [] data;
    }

    T& operator()(size_t row, size_t col) {
        return data[(row * cols) + col];
    }

    T operator()(size_t row, size_t col) const {
        return data[(row * cols) + col];
    }

    matrix<T>& operator=(const matrix<T>& other) {
        if (&other != this) {
            delete[] data;
            rows = other.rows;
            cols = other.cols;
            data = new T[rows*cols];
            std::copy(data, &data[rows*cols], other.data);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    /* for C++11:

    matrix<T>& operator=(matrix<T> &&other) {
        delete[] data;
        data = nullptr;
        rows = cols = 0;

        std::swap(rows, other.rows);
        std::swap(cols, other.cols);
        std::swap(data, other.data);

        return *this;
    }
    */
};
```

However, the [copy-and-swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/) would be safer:

```
template <typename T>
class matrix {
private:
    T* data;
    size_t const rows, cols;

public:
    matrix(size_t rows, size_t cols) : rows(rows), cols(cols) {
        data = new T[rows*cols];
    }

    matrix(const matrix<T> &src) : rows(src.rows), cols(src.cols) {
        data = new T[rows*cols];
        std::copy(data, &data[rows*cols], src.data);
    }

    /* for C++11:

    matrix(matrix<T> &&src) : rows(0), cols(0), data(nullptr) {
        src.swap(*this);
    }
    */

    ~matrix() {
        delete [] data;
    }

    T& operator()(size_t row, size_t col) {
        return data[(row * cols) + col];
    }

    T operator()(size_t row, size_t col) const {
        return data[(row * cols) + col];
    }

    void swap(matrix<T>& other) noexcept
    {
        std::swap(rows, other.rows);
        std::swap(cols, other.cols);
        std::swap(data, other.data);
    }

    matrix<T>& operator=(const matrix<T>& other) {
        if (&other != this) {
            matrix<T>(other).swap(*this);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    /* for C++11:

    matrix<T>& operator=(matrix<T> &&other) {
        other.swap(*this);
        return *this;
    }
    */
};
```

In the latter case, the copy assignment and move assignment operators can be merged together into a single operator in C++11:

```
matrix<T>& operator=(matrix<T> other) {
    other.swap(*this);
    return *this;
}
```

Or, you could just follow the Rule of Zero by using `std::vector` and let the compiler and STL do all of the work for you:

```
template <typename T>
class matrix {
private:
    std::vector<T> data;
    size_t const rows, cols;

public:
    matrix(size_t rows, size_t cols) : rows(rows), cols(cols), data(rows*cols) {
    }

    T& operator()(size_t row, size_t col) {
        return data[(row * cols) + col];
    }

    T operator()(size_t row, size_t col) const {
        return data[(row * cols) + col];
    }
};
```

> Because I don't have a default constructor within the `operator=` function, the data in this is just garbage, right?

No, because `operator=` can only be called on a previously constructed object, just like any other class instance method.

> Even if I had a default constructor would it be called?

In the example you showed, no.

> I would like to clarify that I'm only concerned for a call like this:
>
> ```
> matrix<int> A = B;
> ```

That statement does not call `operator=` at all.  The use of `=` is just syntax sugar, the compiler actually performs *copy construction* as if you had written this instead:

```
matrix<int> A(B);
```

Which requires a copy constructor, which you have not implemented, and the compiler-generated copy constructor is not sufficient to make a deep copy of your array.

*Copy assignment* would look more like this instead:

```
matrix<int> A; // <-- default construction
A = B; // <-- copy assignment
```

```
matrix<int> A(B); // <-- copy construction
A = C; // <-- copy assignment
```

Comment: So in the Rule of Zero example `rows`, `cols` and `data` are taken care of by the default copy constructor?

Comment: @McAngus: yes, the compiler-generated copy constructor and copy assignment operator are both adequate for the `rows` and `cols` members, and for the `data` member when it is a Rule-of-Three/Five/Zero compliant type like `std::vector`.

Answer (score 5):

If you use `std::vector` to store your data, your class becomes a lot simpler

```
template <typename T>
class matrix {
   std::vector<T> data;
public:
    size_t const rows, cols;
    matrix(size_t rows, size_t cols) : rows(rows), cols(cols) {
        data.resize(rows*cols);
    }
    //access data
    T& operator()(size_t row, size_t col) {
        return data[row*cols + col];
    }
}
```

you now no longer have to worry about leaking memory, and you don't need to write a destructor, copy constructor or assignment operator.

Comment: Instead or resize, just `data(rows * cols)` in the initialized list.

Answer (score 2):

> Because I don't have a default constructor within the operator= function, the data in this is just garbage, right?

No.

> Even if I had a default constructor would it be called?

No

---

However, there is a memory leak. You are not deallocating the memory that was allocated when the object was constructed.

Answer (score -1):

You might initialize a `matrix` object and then use `operator=` for this object. In this case, `data` in this `matrix` object would not be garbage because it is already initialized.

If you are using `operator=` for an uninitialized instance of `matrix`,  e.g `matrix<int> a = b;`, where `b` is already initialized, that means you are calling the copy constructor, which is automatically generated by the compiler. In both cases, there are no garbage values.